# Emacs csharp-mode disable auto-pair braces

Tags: emacs

When editing a C# file using `csharp-mode`, every time I type an open brace `{` a closing brace `}` is automatically added on a new line. I'd like to disable this in my `.emacs` file.

Could someone advise how to do this.

I have tried

```
(setq electric-pair-mode nil)
```

but this fails to make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csharp-mode` appears to bind its own function `csharp-insert-open-brace` to `{`. Try rebinding `{` to `c-electric-brace` (which is only electric if you configure it to be). Something like

```
(add-hook 'csharp-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "{") 'c-electric-brace)))
```

should work.

Comment: I encourage you to contact the csharp-mode authors and ask them to obey `electric-pair-mode` (which is a somewhat recent addition to Emacs).